# Rotate functionality is not working on onmousedown?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am following this code to implement rotate function in my paint program: 
http://jsfiddle.net/QqwKR/412/

However, the image img doesn't load up and instead a yellow filled rectangle shows up.

Also when I add the rotate function, the code stops working:

```
function rotate() {

flag = 4;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
w = img.width / 2;
h = img.height / 2;
draw();
}
img.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/new/1-freepik.jpg";

}
```

In html I add the following:

```
<button onclick="rotate()" style="height:100px;width:100px;">rotate</button>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: did you try using the developer console to check for errors?

Comment: yes, I did and it returns false; there are no syntax error, the region that was supposed to be recognised as the rotation handle just returns false so it is no longer returning true and hence you cannot rotate using the handler anymore. I have no idea why it returns false now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big yellow rectangle shows up because you draw a big yellow rectangle over the image. Copied from the code:

```
function drawRect() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, -w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
        ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
        ctx.fillRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h); // <-- Here.
    ctx.restore();
}
```

If you remove those two lines, the handle works just fine.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;


var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;


var cx = canvas.width / 2;
var cy = canvas.height / 2;
var w;
var h;
var r = 0;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    w = img.width / 2;
    h = img.height / 2;
    draw();
}
img.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/new/1-freepik.jpg";


function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawRotationHandle(true);
    drawRect();
}

function drawRect() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, -w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawRotationHandle(withFill) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, -1);
    ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, -1);
    ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, -7);
    ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 30, -7);
    ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 30, 7);
    ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, 7);
    ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 1);
    ctx.closePath();
    if (withFill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
    }
    ctx.restore();
}



function handleMouseDown(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    drawRotationHandle(false);
    isDown = ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY);
    // console.log(isDown);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    var dx = mouseX - cx;
    var dy = mouseY - cy;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    r = angle;
    draw();
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: ivory;
}
#canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<p>Rotate by dragging blue rotation handle</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Regarding the button and the `rotate` function, I have no idea what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: I want to only allow rotate functionality if the person clicks on the button "rotate", otherwise it shouldn't allow you to rotate and the rotationhandle should not be drawn as soon as the page loads up but only when the rotate button is clicked